# RMAN windows client

Tags: oracle, rman

can you please explain me - when I run :

```
rman target sys/<sys_PWD>@SRC_DB auxiliary sys/<sys_pwd>@TRGT_DB
```

from MY WINDOWS PC - will it copy data from SRC_DB  to TRGT_DB through MY WINDOWS PC or directly from SRC_DB  to TRGT_DB?

thank you

Comment: And please keep clear in your head that oracle's terminology here is a bit counter-intuitive.  IN a duplication operation, the 'target' database is actually the _source_, while the 'auxillary' database is the _destination_.

Comment: @EdStevens if one looks at the tnsnames one can see that he is aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

With active duplication, data will be transferred directly between target and auxiliary.

With backup basked duplication, the auxiliary site will read the backup.

Data will not be transferred through your Windows PC.